# Multi-value insert into postgresql with python

Tags: python, postgresql

I want to build a multi-value insert for postgresql like:

```
INSERT INTO mytable 
VALUES 
    (<value a>, <value b>, …, <value x>),
    (<value 1>, <value 2>, …, <value n>),
    (<value A>, <value B>, …, <value Z>)
```

I've a dictionary with tuples.
`foo = [(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9)]`

How can I build the "correct" insert statement? How can I get rid of the brackets..-> [ ]

```
>>> 'INSERT INTO mytable VALUES%s' % [f for f in foo]
'INSERT INTO mytable VALUES[(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9)]'
```

Comment: `'INSERT INTO mytable VALUES%s' % [f for f in foo]` is probably the worst way of handling SQL and variables, since it makes the code prone to SQL injection.

Comment: Are you using psycopg(2/3) or some other library for dealing with Postgres? That should be the way to go, but I don't see it here.

Comment: (Learn how to) use psycopg3, then use [`cursor.executemany`](https://www.psycopg.org/psycopg3/docs/api/cursors.html#psycopg.Cursor.executemany).

Comment: I've psycopg2...

Comment: Psycopg2 also works, and has an executemany method on a cursor. Use that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use one of the [fast execution helpers](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html#fast-execution-helpers), which are *faster* than `executemany`.

[execute_values](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html#psycopg2.extras.execute_values):

```py
import psycopg2
from psycopg2.extras import execute_values

with psycopg2.connect(database='test') as conn:      
    with conn.cursor() as cur:        
        execute_values(cur, """INSERT INTO t74179514 (a, b, c) VALUES %s""", foo)
```

[execute_batch](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html#psycopg2.extras.execute_batch):

```py
import psycopg2
from psycopg2.extras import execute_batch

with psycopg2.connect(database='test') as conn:      
    with conn.cursor() as cur:           
        execute_batch(cur, """INSERT INTO t74179514 (a, b, c) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)""", foo)
```

Comment: The pace of executemany is unacceptable...The execute_values is 5 times slower than the "bad sql injection"...I go with the execute_values. The pace is not the importent part here. Thx